# Do both endpoints in WebRTC need STUN/TURN config/credentials

Tags: webrtc, stun, turn

Working in WebRTC, it would seem like only the offering client would need to provide STUN and TURN locations and credentials that would be encased in the offer and then used by the receiving client(s). Is that the case? If not, why not?

Comment: Did you find an answer to this question? I am looking for an answer to this myself.

Comment: @dentemm I was not able to get it working without giving both sides turn credentials. I am not totally sure why. One possibility is that you can't control which one is going to be dominant in the ICE handshake process. Another possibility is that both sides having credentials creates added security some how. Not really sure, but no matter what I did, I needed to have config and credentials for both peers.

Comment: Thanks for answering Michael! It does indeed seem both sides need the credentials, I also couldn't get it to work otherwise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, clients on both ends need to provide some sort of STUN/TURN configuration, note that these configurations need **not** to be the same.

Recall that STUN and TURN just provides you the tools to get around [NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation). In other words, it provides the tools for a peer to figure out a way to be reachable publicly. They do that by generating ICE candidates that we send through signalling. As long as we can generate at least one valid ICE candidate and tell our peer about it, we can establish a connection.

The reason why both ends need to provide configuration is because otherwise, one of the peers would have no way to tell which IP address belongs to the other. Therefore, even though the answering peer has your ICE candidates (so it knows how to reach you), if the ICE candidates are generated only by the offering side, then this side has no way to securely tell that an incoming connection attempt is actually coming from the peer who you sent your offer to (although it most likely would be).

And for the bounty question "I would like to know if it's possible to connect peers over TURN when only one peer has the required TURN credentials.", the answer is also no.

To understand why, you need to understand that a TURN server is there so in case you can't establish a direct connection due to firewalls, incompatibilities, etc. it generates you "fake" ICE candidates to send to your peer because, in reality, these candidates are actually representing your TURN server. Your TURN server would then relay data sent by your peer to you, at this point, it is not considered peer-to-peer anymore.

That said, your peer doesn't even know about your TURN server, it sees your TURN generated candidates like any other candidate. Your peer still has to gather ICE candidates somehow to send you. And it can't use your TURN server to do that because you never provided its credentials throughout the workflow.

I recommend you read the book [WebRTC For the Curious](https://webrtcforthecurious.com/docs/webrtc-for-the-curious.pdf) if you are interested in this stuff. It's very comprehensive.